# Azure Automation Start-AzureAutomationRunbook error

Tags: azure, automation, runbook

Using Powershell 5.1 runbook.

I'm trying to test sending an email from another runbook.  The SendEmailToDba runbook runs successfully given the same parameters as I'm using in this second runbook.  I cant figure out why it is complaining about the "ResourceGroupName" parameter.  It is a required parameter of Start-AzureAutomationRunbook.

```
$params = @{ "destEmailAddress" = "me@company.com"; "fromEmailAddress" = "me@company.com"; "subject" = "test Email from Runbook"; "content" = "This is a test from another runbook" }
Write-Output( $params )

$job = Start-AzureAutomationRunbook `
            -Name "SendEmailToDba" `
            -Parameters $params `
            -AutomationAccountName "myAccount" `
            -ResourceGroupName "my-automation-resourcegroup"
```

Then I get the following error:

System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ResourceGroupName'.
at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.VerifyArgumentsProcessed(ParameterBindingException originalBindingException)
at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParametersNoValidation(Collection`1 arguments) at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParameters(Collection`1 arguments)
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.BindCommandLineParameters()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoPrepare(IDictionary psDefaultParameterValues)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.Start(Boolean incomingStream)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)
at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `"ResourceGroupName"` doesn't not recognized or wrongly given is coming because of the incorrect command.

`Start-AzureAutomationRunbook` is not a valid `PowerShell` command. You need to use
`Start-AzAutomationRunbook / Start-AzureRMAutomationRunbook` commands to start the automation runbooks.

**Note:**

1. Update the PowerShell runbook version to `7.1 / 7.2` to avoid few concerns.
2. Make sure to have the `Az` & `Az.Automation` PowerShell module installed in the `Azure Automation account -> Modules` to use the `Start-AzAutomationRunbook` cmdlet.
3. Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/start-runbooks).

***I modified your script as below:***

```
connect-Azaccount -identity

$params = @{ "destEmailAddress" = "destmailID"; "fromEmailAddress" = "me@company.com"; "subject" = ""; "content" = "" }

$AutomationAccount = "jahnaviauto"
$Runbook = "myrunbook"
$ResourceGroup = "Jahnavi"
$RunbookParameters = @{
Name = $Runbook
AutomationAccount = $AutomationAccount
ResourceGroup = $ResourceGroup
}
Start-AzAutomationRunbook @RunbookParameters
```

You can change the parameters and the relevant information as per the requirements and try the script.

***Output:***

[image]